# How to prove that the following double sum is always an integer？

Tags: nt.number-theory, co.combinatorics, binomial-coefficients

I have veriﬁed the following double sum is always an integer for $s$ up to $1000$ via Maple.
But I can not prove it. Proofs, hints, or references are all welcome.
Thanks!
$$\sum_{m=s}^{2s}\sum_{k=0}^{s} {2s\choose s}{s\choose k}{m\choose k}{k\choose m-s} \frac{1}{(s+1)(2k-1)(2m-2k-1)}$$

What I have known is that:

(1) Every term is not always an integer, but I can prove that ${2s\choose s}{s\choose k}{m\choose k}{k\choose m-s} \frac{1}{(2k-1)(2m-2k-1)}$ is always an integer.

(2) $\sum_{k=0}^{s} {2s\choose s}{s\choose k}{m\choose k}{k\choose m-s} ={2s\choose s}^2{s\choose m-s}$. This combinatorial identity may be helpful to solve this problem.

**Note:-** The problem has also been posted  [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1042332/how-to-prove-sum-m-s2s-sum-k-0s-2s-choose-ss-choose-km-choose-k).

Comment: Let $a_s$ denote your sum. Any sum like this has to satisfy a linear recurrence relation with polynomial coefficients. Some experimentation suggests that we have $$(7s+8)(s+4)(s+3)a_{s+3} - 4(56s^2+127s+57)(s+3)(s+2)a_{s+2} - 16(7s^4-6s^3-121s^2-210s-90)a_{s+1} + 128(7s+15)(2s+3)(2s+1)(s-1)a_s = 0$$ for all $s \ge 0$. There are quite algorithmic ways to prove such a relation. The question is if it can actually help with the problem.

Comment: Also posted to m.se --- you should put a link at each site to the question at the other site.

Comment: Never mind; http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1042332/how-to-prove-sum-m-s2s-sum-k-0s-2s-choose-ss-choose-km-choose-k

Comment: Is there any background?

Comment: Since the Catalan numbers are involved and we always (presumably) get an integer value, it looks like this sum denumerates specific portions of e.g. trees. So, it would be nice to find some combinatorial arguments which might be helpful to considerably simplify this double sum and answer OPs question as side-effect. In fact, I'm first of all interested in simplifying this double sum.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Here is an attempt at an answer. We assume that the recurrence from my comment above holds [with a small correction] (a proof was obtained by Kevin using Zeilberger's algorithm, see the comment below):
$$ (7s+8)(s+4)(s+3)^2 a_{s+3} - 4(56s^2+127s+57)(s+3)(s+2) a_{s+2} $$
$$ - 16(7s^4-6s^3-121s^2-210s-90) a_{s+1} + 128(7s+15)(2s+3)(2s+1)(s-1) a_s = 0 $$
Write $a_s = b_s/(s+1)$. According to Kevin's claim (1), $b_s \in \mathbb Z$. Now
the sequence $(b_s)$ satisfies the recurrence
$$ (7s+8)(s+3)^2(s+2)(s+1) b_{s+3} - 4(56s^2+127s+57)(s+2)^2(s+1) b_{s+2} $$
$$     - 16(7s^4-6s^3-121s^2-210s-90)(s+1) b_{s+1}
     + 128(7s+15)(2s+3)(2s+1)(s+2)(s-1) b_s = 0 .$$
We want to show that $s+1$ divides $b_s$. By the recurrence, we have that
$$ (s+1) \mid 128(7s+15)(2s+3)(2s+1)(s+2)(s-1) b_s . $$
Since the gcd of $s+1$ with the factor in front of $b_s$ is a power of 2, we can conclude that the odd part of $s+1$ divides $b_s$. On the other hand, it is easy to see that each term in the sum for $a_s$ is 2-adically integral (it is a 
Catalan number times some binomial coefficients times a fraction with odd
denominator), so there is no need to consider the 2-power part of $s+1$.

Comment: I verify the recurrence via maple, and find $a_s$ don't satisfy the recurrence. Could you tell me how you find this third-order recurrence? If the right recurrence is found, it is helpful to solve this problem. Thanks!

Comment: Did you use the corrected version (with $(s+3)^2$ in the coefficient of $a_{s+3}$)? Just to check that I did compute the $a_s$ correctly: my sequence starts with $1, 0, 16, 96, 832, 9728, 140288, 2327552, \ldots$ (and is not in the OEIS).

Comment: I use the corrected version and verify it via maple, it is correct recurrence, you are right! The sequence is not in OEIS. I can't find the recurrence  by zeilberger algorithm.  How do you find the recurrence?Thank you very much!

Comment: I found the (likely) recurrence by looking for a linear dependence between the sequences $(s^j a_{s+k})$ for small values of $j$ and $k$. I'll try to produce a proof later.

Comment: Regarding the recurrence: In principle, this is a matter of linear algebra. However, with all the approaches I tried, the linear systems got too large to be solved (without using special software or tricks, at any rate) before a nontrivial relation emerged. (See the book "A=B" by Petkovsek, Wilf and Zeilberger for ways of doing this: http://www.math.upenn.edu/~wilf/AeqB.html.) So I give up. Perhaps the question should be changed to ask for a proof of the recurrence relation...

Comment: Thank you for your good ideas and suggestions for this question. I have proved the third-order recurrence by Multi-Varible Zeilberger algorithm. In my proof, I obtain a very complicated fifth-order recurrence. What I have done is that: $M(s),N(s)$ denote the third recurrence and fifth-order recurrence respectively. Then I prove $c_0(s)N(s)+d_0(s)M(s)+d_1(s)M(s+1)+d_2(s)M(s+2)=0$ where $c_0(s),d_0(s),d_1(s),d_2(s)$ are polynomials with integer coefficients, from this fact, I prove the third-order recurrence by induction. If proof without software is found, it will be better.

Comment: I doubt that there will be a proof completely without using software. But usually the Zeilberger approach produces (using software) a relation satisfied by the terms in the sum that can be checked by hand (at least in principle, or by some other independent software) and which implies the desired recurrence.