# How to prove this polynomial always has integer values at all integers?

Tags: nt.number-theory, co.combinatorics, polynomials, binomial-coefficients

Let $m$ be any positive integer.
$$
P_m(x)=\sum_{i=0}^{m}\sum_{j=0}^{m}{x+j\choose j}{x-1\choose j}{j\choose i}{m\choose i}{i\choose m-j}\frac{3}{(2i-1)(2j+1)(2m-2i-1)}.
$$
Question: $P_m(x)$ always has integer values at all integers.

Some remarks:

(1)  A polynomial is $\mathbb Z$-valued iff its unique expansion in basis $\left\{{x\choose k}\right\}$ has $\mathbb Z$-coefficients. This idea was Allen Knutson's.
For $m=1,2,3,4$, I list the polynomials in this basis, which is more clear that $P_m(x)$ is $\mathbb Z$-valued.
\begin{align*}
P_1(x)&=-4{x\choose 2}-2{x\choose 1}+2,\\
P_2(x)&=12{x\choose 4}+18{x\choose 3}+6{x\choose 2},\\
P_3(x)&=48{x\choose 6}+120{x\choose 5}+96{x\choose 4}+24{x\choose 3},\\
P_4(x)&=236{x\choose 8}+826{x\choose 7}+1070{x\choose 6}+610{x\choose
5}+134{x\choose 4}+4{x\choose 3}
\end{align*}

(2) Since ${-x+j\choose j}{-x-1\choose j}={x+j\choose j}{x-1\choose j}$, we have $P_m(-x)=P_m(x)$. Let $q_j(x)={x\choose 2j}+{-x\choose 2j}.$ Then
\begin{align*}
P_1(x)&=-2q_1(x)+2\\
P_2(x)&=6q_2(x)-6q_1(x)\\
P_3(x)&=24q_3(x)-72q_2(x)+48q_1(x)\\
P_4(x)&=118q_4(x)-704q_3(x)+1522q_2(x)-936q_1(x)\\
P_5(x)&=696q_5(x)-6900q_4(x)+30960q_3(x)-63252q_2(x)+38496q_1(x)\\
P_6(x)&=4824q_6(x)-71640q_5(x)+547572q_4(x)\\
&-2345904q_3(x)+4757916q_2(x)-2892768q_1(x).
\end{align*}
This idea was given by Wilberd van der Kallen.

(3) Let $S_m(x)=xP_m(x)$. Then
$$
S_m(x)=\sum_{i=0}^{m}\sum_{j=0}^{m}{x+j\choose 2j+1}{2j\choose j}{m\choose i}{j\choose i}{i\choose m-j}\frac{3}{(2i-1)(2m-2i-1)}.
$$
Note that ${2j\choose j}{m\choose i}{j\choose i}{i\choose m-j}\frac{1}{(2i-1)(2m-2i-1)}$ is an integer (I can prove this). So the question is equivalent to $$n|S_m(n)$$ for any positive integer $n,m$.

(4) It is easy to see that letting $|x|\le \left\lfloor \frac{m+1}{2} \right\rfloor$ be a integer, we have
$$
{x+j\choose j}{x-1\choose j}{j\choose i}{m\choose i}{i\choose m-j}=0.
$$
Then $P_m(n)=0$ for any integer $|n|\le \left\lfloor \frac{m+1}{2} \right\rfloor$.

Comment: Related question: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/190549/how-to-prove-that-the-following-double-sum-is-always-an-integer

Comment: (1) The proper basis for the space of integer-valued polynomials is not monomials $\{x^k\}$ but binomial coefficients $\{ {x\choose k} \}$ (a polynomial is $\mathbb Z$-valued iff its unique expansion in this basis has $\mathbb Z$-coefficients). You should probably look into those expansions. (2) Let $Q(x) = P(x+1)+P(x-1)-2P(x)$, again even. If $P$ is $\mathbb Z$-valued, so is $Q$, and I suspect the converse is true for even functions (assuming $Q(0) \in \mathbb Z$). Perhaps you can use this for an inductive argument.

Comment: @Allen Knutson, Thank you for your useful idea. I have listed the polynomials in basis $\{ {x\choose k} \}$. I think it is also hard to prove that $Q(x)$ is $\mathbb Z$-valued as you mentioned.

Comment: @AllenKnutson: Your comment (2) is a consequence of your comment (1) (and the converse is indeed true), because mapping $P$ to $Q$ in your notation has the effect of sending $\sum a_n \binom{x}{n}$ to $\sum a_{n + 2} \binom{x}{n}$, possibly up to some indexing shift.

Comment: @Kevin Maybe you have a "combinatorial interpretation" for your polynomials ? that means that your polynomials count something (like the hook formula) so that, for some $x\geq N(m)$ and $x\in \mathbb{N}$, you have $P_m(x)\in \mathbb{N}$. In this case, you can conclude.

Comment: @DavidLoeffler : yes it has that effect, which means we've lost control of $a_0$ and $a_1$. I wrote "(assuming $Q(0)\in\mathbb Z$)" but meant $P(0)\in\mathbb Z$. How are you using evenness to control $a_1$, to establish this converse?

Comment: I really don't know how to connect $\mathbb Z$-valuedness and evenness. If $x^2=y$ so we can rewrite $P(x)$ as $P(y)$, then $P$ being $\mathbb Z$-valued at all $y\in\mathbb Z$ is (much?) stronger than its being $\mathbb Z$-valued at all $x\in\mathbb Z$. Do your computed polynomials have $\mathbb Z$-coefficients expanded in $\{ {y \choose k} \}$?

Comment: I have two questions/suggestions. Are the parts for fixed $i$ integer-valued? Are there some linear recursions on $P_m(x)$?

Comment: Given the form of the original expression, you might also try expanding in the basis $x+k\choose k$, to see if the coefficients look any nicer.  By the way, does it seem that the coefficients of $P_m(x)$ in the $x\choose k$ basis are nonnegative for $m>1$?

Comment: Put $q_n(x)={x\choose n}+{-x\choose n}$. Notice that $P_4(x)=-936q_2(x)+1522q_4(x)-704q_6(x)+118q_8(x)$. So it looks like the $P_n$ are integer combinations of the $q_{2n}$.

Comment: @Allen Knutson. My $q_{2n}$ span the space of even polynomials with integer values and with even value at zero. One sees this by showing that the determinant of the $(q_{2n}(i))$ matrix, $i=1,\dots,m$, $n=1,\dots,m$ equals one. Then your suspicion follows "easily".

Comment: Comparing the leading coefficient of $P_m(x)$ with that of $\binom{x}{2m}$, one gets that $\frac{3}{(2m+1)(m-1)}\binom{2m}{m}\sum_{i=0}^m\binom{m}{i}^2\frac{1}{2i-1}$ is an integer provided that $P_m(\mathbb Z)\subseteq\mathbb Z$. Is this integrality known? I don't know if there is a closed expression for the sum.

Comment: @Kevin - could you tell us how you arrived at this formula? May be this would inspire some arguments...

Comment: @Kevin: its unlikely that this allows a closed form, but I don't have $A=B$, nor hyp.m handy.  In any case, guessing the reccurrence yields $(m+2)^2(2m+5)(3m+2)f(m+2)-4m(30m^3+110m^2+128m+47)f(m+1)+32(m-1)(2m+1)^2(3m+5)f(m)=0$.

Comment: @Martin Rubey, The recurrence you gave was true only if $x=1$. For $x\ge 2$, $P_m(x)$ no longer satisfy the recurrence.

Comment: @ Peter Mueller, Comparing the leading coefficient, we have $\sum_{i=0}^{m}{2m\choose m}{m\choose i}^2\frac{3}{(2i-1)(2m-2i-1)(2m+1)}$ is an integer. I think this sum has not a closed form. However, it is not difficulty to prove that it is an integer.

Comment: @Kevin: sorry for being unclear.  The recurrence should be true for your sum, i.e., the leading coefficient of $P_m(x)$, not for $P_m(x)$ itself.

Comment: There is something unnatural in the sum, so without any context it shows up it is hard to think of the options.
(1) It is sufficient to establish the integral-valuedness of $P(x)$ by showing it for $1+\deg P$ consecutive integer values. The vanishing and symmetry of $P_m$ subsequently reduces the range.
(2) The inner sum over $i$ is a well-poised $_4F_3(1)$ hypergeometric series; there are several transformations available for it but experimenting with them is time consuming.

Comment: (3) Representation by means of $B_k(x)=\binom{x+k}{2k}+\binom{-x+k}{2k}$ is more economical, as $P_m(x)$ experimentally appears to be $\mathbb Z$-linear combination of $B_k(x)$ with $k>(m+1)/2$.

Comment: @Wadim Zudilin. This $B_k$ basis is great. It shows for instance that it suffices to prove that $P_m(x)$ is an integer for integer $x$ between 0 and $m$.

Comment: In Wadim's basis it is easy to guess a second order recurrence $a(n) f_{n+2} + b(n) f_{n+1} + c(n) f_n = 0$ for any given coefficient.  It appears that only $b(n)$ contains a nonlinear factor.  Apparently, $a(n)=(n-i+1)(n+2)(n+i+1)(2n+2i+3)(3n+i+1)$, $b(n)=(n+i-1)p(n,i)$, $c(n)=32(n+i-2)(n+i-1)(2n+1)^2(3n+i+4)$ and $p(n,i)$ is some polynomial of degree 4 in $n$.  Not sure how much this helps.

Comment: In fact, $b(n) = -(n+i-1)(120n^4 + 8(17i+38)n^3 + 8(i+1)(i+31)n^2 -4(2i^3+8i^2-36i-21)n-4(i-1)(4i^2+10i+3)$.

Comment: Experimentally
${x+j\choose j}{x-1\choose j}$ equals 
$\sum_{k=0}^j  (-1)^{k+j} {2k\choose k} B_k(x)/2$.
So $P_m(x)=\sum_{k=0}^m 
\sum_{i=0}^m\sum_{j=k}^m\frac{
3(-1)^{k+j}{2k  \choose k }{j  \choose  i}{ m \choose i }{i  \choose m-j }}{2(2i-1)(2j+1)(2m-2i-1)}
B_k(x)$ and one must show that 
$\sum_{i=0}^m\sum_{j=k}^m\frac{
3(-1)^{k+j}{2k  \choose k }{j  \choose  i}{ m \choose i }{i  \choose m-j }}{2(2i-1)(2j+1)(2m-2i-1)}$
is an integer for $1\leq k\leq m$. Is this any easier?

Comment: $\sum_{i=0}^m\sum_{j=k}^m\frac{3 (-1)^{k+j}{2k  \choose k }{j  \choose  i}{ m \choose i }{i  \choose m-j }}{2(2i-1)(2j+1)(2m-2i-1)}$ equals $\sum_{i=0}^m\sum_{j=0}^{k-1}\frac{3 (-1)^{k+j}{2k  \choose k }{j  \choose  i}{ m \choose i }{i  \choose m-j }}{2(2i-1)(2j+1)(2m-2i-1)}$ for $k>1$.

Comment: @Wilberd van der Kallen, I have verified via maple the identity $\sum_{i=0}^m\sum_{j=0}^m\frac{3 (-1)^{k+j}{2k  \choose k }{j  \choose  i}{ m \choose i }{i  \choose m-j }}{2(2i-1)(2j+1)(2m-2i-1)}=0$ for $m\ge 2$, which is interesting.

Comment: That must have been what I meant.

Comment: It is nice to see that it is now reduced to showing that $$\frac32\binom{2k}{k}\sum_{j=0}^{k-1}\frac{c_{m,j}}{2j+1}\in\mathbb Z$$ for $k>[(m+1)/2]$, where
$$c_{m,j}=\sum_{i=0}^m\frac{\binom{j}{i}\binom{m}{i}\binom{i}{m-j}}{(2i-1)(2m-2i-1)}.$$ The summation 4.6.1 from Bailey's book on Hypergeometric Functions
transforms the coefficients to
$$c_{m,j}=\frac{j!}{(1/2)_j(-m+1/2)_{j+1}(m-j)!}\sum_{n=[(m+1)/2]}^j\frac{(1/2)_n(-1/2)_n(-m+1/2)_n}{n!(2n-m)!}2^{2n-1},$$
where $(x)_n=\Gamma(x+n)/\Gamma(x)=x(x+1)\cdots(x+n-1)$ is Pochhammer's symbol.

Comment: @Wadim Zudilin, could you tell me why you apply hypergeometric functions transforms? I think your idea may lead us to the solution.

Comment: Hypergeometric identities/transformations are often used to write different representations that are transparently integer-valued; see, e.g., http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0311195 or http://mathoverflow.net/questions/26336. In the present case the sum $\sum_{j=k}^m\frac{(-1)^jc_{m,j}}{2j+1}$ (I missed the sign $(-1)^j$ in the previous comment) assumes a completely different binomial form, and one can swap the summations over $j$ and $n$. Then the newer inner sum over $m-j$ (rather than $j$) is a partial sum of the Gauss hypergeometric function, so that one can use some further transformations...

Answer (score 35, accepted):

$$P_m(x)=\sum_{i=0}^{m}\sum_{j=0}^{m}\binom{x+j}{ j}\binom{x-1}{ j}\binom{j}{ i}\binom{m}{ i}\binom{i}{ m-j}\frac{3}{(2i-1)(2j+1)(2m-2i-1)}.$$

Our task is to show it takes integer values on integers.
Folowing Wadim Zudilin we put 
$$B_k(x)=\binom{x+k}{2k}+\binom{-x+k}{2k}.$$

For $k\geq0$ the $B_k$ are even polynomials of degree $2k$ that take integer values on integers. One has $B_k(k)=1$ for $k\geq1$, but $B_0(0)=2$. Further $B_k(i)=0$ for $|i|<k$. 
So the matrix $$(B_k(i))_{0\leq k\leq m}^{0\leq i\leq  m}$$ is triangular.

Every even polynomial $f(x)$ of degree $2j$ is clearly a linear combination of $B_0,\dots,B_j$ and the coefficients are determined by $f(0),\dots,f(j)$.
When $f(0)=0$ it is actually a linear combination of  $B_1,\dots,B_j$.

Rewrite $P_m(x)$ as $$P_m(x)=\sum_k d(m,k)B_k(x)$$ with $d(m,k)\in\mathbb{Q}$. As explained by Kevin, $P_m(k)$ vanishes if 
 $m>2|k|-2\geq0$ because all terms in the sum vanish. It can also be shown that  $P_m(0)=0$ for $m\geq2$, but that is more tricky. 
 Indeed we will show that $d(m,0)=0$ for $m\geq2$.

Note that $P_m(x)$ visibly lies in the local ring $\mathbb{Z}_{(2)}$ for integer $x$.
So it suffices to show that $d(m,k)$ lies in $\mathbb{Z}_{(p)}$ for any  odd prime $p$. 
In fact we will find that the $d(m,k)$ are integers for $m\geq1$. And $d(0,0)=3/2$ lies in $\mathbb{Z}_{(p)}$ for our odd prime $p$.
 For $m$ not too large one may simply compute all $d(m,k)$.
The matrix $$(d(m,k))_{0\leq m\leq10}^{0\leq k\leq10}$$ looks like this
$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccccccccccc}
 \frac{3}{2} & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 1 & -2 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 6 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 24 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 4 & 118 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 60 & 696 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 12 & 720 & 4824 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 336 & 8288 & 38240 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 60 & 6516 & 95928 & 336822 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 2520 & 109872 & 1131732 & 3215544 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 392 & 67904 & 1735320 & 13647840 & 32651544 \\
\end{array}
\right).$$
We will tacitly use it to deal with small values of $m$.

We will study the set $$V_p=\{ (m,k)\in \mathbb{Z}\times \mathbb{Z} \mid d(m,k)\in \mathbb{Z}_{(p)}\}.$$

Using a method of Zeilberger we will prove relations between the $d(m,k)$ that were first discovered experimentally.
 One relation allows us to rewrite  $m(m-1)(1 + 2 m) d(m, k)$ in such a manner that we can use
 the method of Floors described in

[question 26336](https://mathoverflow.net/q/26336).

With that method we show that $m(m-1)(1 + 2 m) d[m, k]$ is an integer multiple of $3m(m-1)$.
 Together with the relations this will allow us to show that $V_p$
 fills all of $ \mathbb{Z}\times \mathbb{Z}$ for odd primes $p$.

Our variables 
$i,j,k,m,n,q$ will 
take integer values only.

As in the A=B book we use the convention that $\binom{x}{j}$ is a polynomial in $x$ for fixed $j$. And it is the zero polynomial if $j<0$. So $\binom i j$ is defined for all integers $i$, $j$. It also vanishes  if $j>i\geq0$. Of course $\binom{i}{j}$  agrees with the usual binomial coefficient if $0\leq j\leq i$.

By inspecting the values at $x=0,\dots,j,$ we see that $$(-1)^j\binom{x+j}{j}\binom{x-1}{j}-(-1)^{j-1}\binom{x+j-1}{j-1}\binom{x-1}{j-1}$$ equals $(-1)^j\binom{2j}{j}B_j(x)/2$ for $j\geq0$.
Taking the telescoping sum over $j$ gives $$(-1)^j\binom{x+j}{j}\binom{x-1}{j}=\sum_{k=0}^j(-1)^k\binom{2j}{j}B_k(x)/2$$ for $j\geq0$. (Valid for all $j$, actually).

This allows us to conclude that
$$d(m,k)=\sum_{i=0}^m\sum_{j=k}^m\frac{ 3(-1)^{k+j}\binom{2k  }{ k }\binom{j  }{  i}\binom{ m }{ i }\binom{i  }{ m-j }}{2(2i-1)(2j+1)(2m-2i-1)}.$$

In particular $d(m,k)=0$ for $m<0$ and for $k>m$. We will see that $m(m-1)d(m,k)$ also vanishes for
$2k-2<m$.

Let us use the notation $[$statement$]=
\begin{cases}1,&\text{if statement is true;}\\ 0,&\text{otherwise.}\end{cases}$

Then 
\begin{align}
d(m,k)=&\sum_{i,j}[j\geq k\geq0] \text{term}(m,k,i,j), \tag{$\Sigma ij$}
\end{align}

where $$\text{term}(m,k,i,j)=[m\geq0]\frac{3(-1)^{k+j}\binom{2k  }{ k }\binom{j  }{  i}\binom{ m }{ i }\binom{i  }{ m-j }}{2(2i-1)(2j+1)(2m-2i-1)}.$$

Put

\begin{align*}
\text{rel1}&(m,k)
 = \\
   -& 32 (3-2 k)^2 (-k+m+1)
   (-k+m+2) d(m,k-2)\\
 +&4 (-k+m+1) \left(2 k m^2-2 (k-1) (8 k-9) m+(2 k-3) (8
   (k-2) k+9)\right) d(m,k-1)\\
   + & k (-2 k+m+2) (-2 k+m+3) (-2 k+2
   m+1) d(m,k),
\end{align*}

\begin{align*}
\text{rel2}&(m,k)
 = \\&-4 \left((m-1)^2-1\right) d(m-1,k-1)\\&-4 (2 (k-1)+m+1)
   (-k+m+1) d(m,k-1)\\&+k (2 k-m-2) d(m,k)
 \end{align*}

**Key results**

$\bullet$ $\text{rel1}(m,k)$  vanishes.

$\bullet$ $m(m-1)d(m,k)$ vanishes for $2k-2<m$.

$\bullet$ $\text{rel2}(m,k)$ vanishes.

$\bullet$ $m(m-1)( 2 m+1) d(m, k)$ is an integer multiple of $3m(m-1)$.

Before proving the Key results, let us draw conclusions from them. Let $m\geq2$. As $d(m,0)=0$, we have $P_m(0)=0$ and the $d(m,k)$ are 
determined by $P_m(1)\dots,P_m(m)$. 
Now the integral matrix $$(B_k(i))_{1\leq k\leq m}^{1\leq i\leq  m}$$ is triangular with ones on the diagonal.
We conclude that $d(m,k)\in \mathbb{Z}_{(2)}$ for $m\geq2$.

Let $p$ be a prime, $p\geq5$, and let $m\geq 2$.
If $p$ does not divide $2m+1$, then $d(m,k)\in \mathbb{Z}_{(p)}$ because $m(m-1)( 2 m+1) d(m, k)\in 3m(m-1)\mathbb{Z}_{(p)}$.
Now assume $p$ divides $2m+1$. Then it does not divide $2m+3$, so then $d(m+1,j)\in \mathbb{Z}_{(p)}$ for all $j$.
Also, $p$ does not divide $(m-1)(m+1)$, so it follows from $\text{rel2}(m+1,k+1)=0$ that $d(m,k)\in \mathbb{Z}_{(p)}$.
We have shown that  $d(m,k)\in \mathbb{Z}_{(p)}$ if  $p$ is prime, $p\geq5$, $m\geq2$.

Remains $p=3$. Let $m\geq2$ again.

If $3$ does not divide $2m+1$, then $d(m,k)\in 3\mathbb{Z}_{(3)}$ because $m(m-1)( 2 m+1) d(m, k)\in 3m(m-1)\mathbb{Z}_{(3)}$.

If $m\equiv1$ mod 9, or $m\equiv7$ mod 9, then $(2m+1)/3$ is prime to $3$ and $d(m,k)\in \mathbb{Z}_{(3)}$ because $m(m-1)(( 2 m+1)/3 )d(m, k)\in m(m-1)\mathbb{Z}_{(3)}$.

If $m\equiv 4$ mod 9, then $(m-1)(m+1)/3$ is prime to 3 and $d(m,k)\in \mathbb{Z}_{(3)}$ because $\text{rel2}(m+1,k+1)=0$ shows 
$((m-1)(m+1)/3)d(m,k)$ is an integer linear combination of the integers $d(m+1,j)/3$.

We conclude that $d(m,k)\in \mathbb{Z}_{(3)}$ for $m\geq2$.
So the $d(m,k)$ are integers for $m\geq2$ and $P_m$ takes integer values on integers for $m\geq2$.
Recall that $P_0$, $P_1$ also take integer values. **Done**.

**So we still have to prove the Key results**.

First a technical issue.
If $x>0$ then $\binom{x}{j}=\frac{\Gamma(1+x)}{\Gamma(1+j)\Gamma(1+x-j)}$ and the bimeromorphic function $$f(x,y)=\frac{\Gamma(1+x)}{\Gamma(1+y)\Gamma(1+x-y)}$$ is continuous at $(x,j)$. However, if $i<0$ then $f$ has an indeterminate value at $(i,j)$. For example, $\binom{i}{i}$ equals $1$ if $i\geq0$, but it vanishes for $i<0$. At $(-1,-1)$ both $0$ and $1$ are values of $f$. Indeed Mathematica can be steered to give either answer.

$\mathtt {Binomial[i,j]~ /.~ i->-1~/.~j->-1}$ gives 1 
and

$\mathtt {Binomial[i,j]~ /. ~j->-1~/.~i->-1}$ gives 0.

And  $\mathtt{FullSimplify[Binomial[i, i] == Binomial[i - 1, i - 1]]}$ yields $\mathtt {True}$.
This answer is correct, but it tells only that for generic complex numbers $i$ the
identity holds.

Thus we need to make case distinctions when using identities between multimeromorphic functions, explicitly or implicitly, to prove identities involving
the $\binom{i}{j}$.

We start proving that $\text{rel1}(m,k)$ vanishes.

As $[j\geq k+1]\big(2 (2 k+1)\text{term}(m,k,i,j)+(k+1)\text{term}(m,k+1,i,j)\big)=0$, we get from $(\Sigma ij)$ that

\begin{align}
2 (2 k+1) d(m,k)+(k+1) d(m,k+1)=&\sum_i \text{iterm}(m,k,i)\tag{$\Sigma i$}
\end{align}
where $$\text{iterm}(m,k,i)=2 (2 k+1)\text{term}(m,k,i,k).$$

Now we use the

```
Fast Zeilberger Package version 3.61
written by Peter Paule, Markus Schorn, and Axel Riese
Copyright 1995-2015, Research Institute for Symbolic Computation (RISC),
Johannes Kepler University, Linz, Austria.
```

It suggests to put

$$g(m,k,i)=\frac{3\times 2^{2 k+3} m (-2 i+m+1) \Gamma \left(k+\frac{3}{2}\right) \binom{k+1}{i-1}
   \binom{m-1}{k+1} \binom{k+1}{m-i}}{\Gamma \left(\frac{1}{2}\right) (k+1)!}$$

and show that
\begin{align*}
-32 (1 + 2 k) &(3 + 2 k) (k - m) (1 + k - m) \text{iterm}(m, k, i) \\
   -4 (1 + k - m) & (57 + 110 k + 72 k^2 + 16 k^3 - 34 m - 46 k m - 
   16 k^2 m + 4 m^2 + 2 k m^2)\\&\times \text{iterm}(m, k+1, i)\\
-(2 + k) (5 +  &2 k - 2 m) (3 + 2 k - m) (4 + 2 k - m)\text{iterm}(m, k+2, i)
 \\
  & -g(m, k, i + 1) +g(m, k, i)=0
\end{align*}

for $m\geq0$, $k\geq0$.
So we do that and then sum over $i$, using $(\Sigma i)$. The $g$ terms drop out by telescoping and we get a relation 
\begin{align*}
-32 (1 + 2 k) &(3 + 2 k) (k - m) (1 + k - m) (2 (2 k+1) d(m,k)+(k+1) d(m,k+1) )\\
   -4 (1 + k - m) & (57 + 110 k + 72 k^2 + 16 k^3 - 34 m - 46 k m - 
   16 k^2 m + 4 m^2 + 2 k m^2)\\&\times  (2 (2 k+3) d(m,k+1)+(k+2) d(m,k+2) )\\
-(2 + k) (5 +  &2 k - 2 m) (3 + 2 k - m) (4 + 2 k - m) \\\times(2 (2 k+5) &d(m,k+2)+(k+3) d(m,k+3) )
 \\
  & =0
\end{align*}
valid for $k\geq0$, as it is obvious for $m<0$.
We may rewrite it as a recursion for $\text{ rel1}$:
$$2 (3 + 2 k) \text{rel1}(m, k + 2) + (2 + k)\text{ rel1}(m, k + 3)=0$$
for $k\geq0$.
As $d(m,k)$ vanishes for $k>m$, it follows from the recursion that $\text{rel1}(m, k )$ vanishes for $k\geq2$.

Put
$$\text{pterm}(m,x,i,j)=\binom{x+j}{ j}\binom{x-1}{ j}\binom{j}{ i}\binom{m}{ i}\binom{i}{ m-j}\frac{3}{(2i-1)(2j+1)(2m-2i-1)},$$
so that 
$$P_m(x)=\sum_{i,j}\text{pterm}(m,x,i,j).$$
If $k\geq1$ and $\text{pterm}[m,k,i,j]$ is nonzero, then 
$ k-1\geq j$ and $m\geq j \geq i \geq m-j $. We see that $$P_m(k)=0 \text{ if }0\leq 2k-2<m,$$ because all the $\text{pterm}(m,k,i,j)$ vanish.
In particular we get
$$0=P_m(1)=\sum_kd(m,k)B_k(1)=2d(m,0)+d(m,1),$$ and $$0=P_m(2)=\sum_kd(m,k)B_k(2)=2d(m,0)+4d(m,1)+d(m,2)$$ for $ m\geq 3$.
So then $d(m,1)=-2d(m,0)$ and $d(m,2)=6d(m,0)$. Substitute this into $\text{rel1}(m, 2 )=0$ and you find 
$$4 m (m - 1) (-2 m - 1) d(m, 0)=0.$$
This means that $d(m, 0)=0$ for $m\geq3$. As $d(2,0)$ also vanishes, we now have enough to conclude that
\begin{align}
m(m-1)d(m,k) \text{ vanishes for }&m>2k-2. \tag{SSE}
\end{align}

It is now easy to see that  $\text{rel1}(m, k )$ also vanishes for $k<2$.

**So we have established the vanishing of** $\text{rel1}(m, k )$ **and the vanishing of**
$m(m-1)d(m,k)$ **for** $m>2k-2$.

Before turning to  $\text{rel2}(m, k )$ we compute $d(2k-2,k)$ and $d(2k-3,k)$ for $k\geq3$. These are the values that help to compute all $d(m,k)$ 
recursively with the recursion given by $\text{rel1}(m, k )$=0.
As $d(2k-2,j)$ vanishes for $j<k$, one has $$d(2k-2,k)=P_{2k-2}(k)=\text{pterm}(2k-2,k,k-1,k-1)$$
and similarly
$$d(2k-3,k)=P_{2k-3}(k)=\text{pterm}(2k-3,k,k-1,k-2)+\text{pterm}(2k-3,k,k-1,k-1).$$
So we know $d(m,k)$ for $m\geq 2k-3\geq3$. By (SSE) we also know  $d(m,k)$  for $k\leq1$ and any $m$.
Using these values we get $\text{rel2}(m,k)=0$ by inspection for $m\geq 2k-3$ or $k\leq1$.
Notice that $(-7+2 k)\text{rel2}(2k-4,k)-\text{rel1}(2k-4,k)$ is a combination of the known terms $ d(-5 + 2 k, -1 + k)$, 
$    d(-4 + 2 k, -2 + k)$,  $  d(-4 + 
  2 k, -1 + k)$. It also vanishes by inspection, so we now have that $\text{rel2}(m,k)=0$ for $m\geq 2k-4$ or $k\leq1$.

By substituting the definitions and expanding we check that
\begin{align*}
&(-1 + k) (-1 + 2 k - 2 m) (-3 + 2 k - m)(4 - 2 k + m) \text{rel2}(m, k)
\\& + 
 4 (-1 + (-1 + m)^2) \text{rel1}(m - 1, k - 1)
 \\& - 
 32 (5 - 2 k)^2 (-2 + k - m) (-1 + k - m) \text{rel2}(m, k - 2)
 \\& + 
 4 (1 - k + m)\\&\times (-99 + 16 k^3 - 2 m (32 + m) - 8 k^2 (11 + 2 m) + 
2 k (81 + m (31 + m))) \text{rel2}(m, k - 1)
   \\& - (-1 + k) (-4 + 2 k - m)\text{ rel1}(m, k)\\&  - 
 4 (-1 + k - m) (-5 + 2 k + m) \text{rel1}(m, k - 1)
 \\&=0
 \end{align*}

As $\text{rel1}$ vanishes, this leads to the following recursion for $\text{rel2}$.
\begin{align*}
&(-1 + k) (-1 + 2 k - 2 m) (-3 + 2 k - m)(4 - 2 k + m) \text{rel2}(m, k) \\& - 
 32 (5 - 2 k)^2 (-2 + k - m) (-1 + k - m) \text{rel2}(m, k - 2)
 \\& + 
 4 (1 - k + m)\\&\times (-99 + 16 k^3 - 2 m (32 + m) - 8 k^2 (11 + 2 m) + 
2 k (81 + m (31 + m))) \text{rel2}(m, k - 1)
   \\&=0
 \end{align*}

As $\text{rel2}(m,k)=0$ for $ 2k-4\leq m$ or $k\leq1$,  the recursion shows by induction on $k$
that $\text{rel2}(m,k)=0$ for all $m$, $k$.

**So we have also established the vanishing of** $\text{rel2}(m,k)$ and it is time to
show the Key result that $m(m-1)( 2 m+1) d(m, k)$ is an integer multiple of $3m(m-1)$. 
This is obvious for $m<2$, so we further assume $m\geq2$. Then we know that $d(m,0)=0$ and we have seen this implies
$d(m,k)\in \mathbb{Z}_{(2)}$. So it suffices to
show that $m(m-1)( 2 m+1) d(m, k)\in 3m(m-1)\mathbb{Z}[1/2]$.

Using relation $(\Sigma i)$ we may rewrite $\text{rel1}(m,k)=0$ as
\begin{align*}&2 (m-1 ) m ( 2 m+1) d(m, k-1 )\\&+
(2 - 2 k + m) (3 - 2 k + m) (1 - 2 k + 2 m) \sum_i \text{iterm}(m, k - 1,i)\\&+ 
 16 (3 - 2 k) (-2 + k - m) (-1 + k - m) \sum_i \text{iterm}(m, k - 2,i) \\&=0
 \end{align*}

We claim that 
\begin{align*}&(2 - 2 k + m) (3 - 2 k + m) (1 - 2 k + 2 m)  \text{iterm}(m, k - 1,i)\\&+ 
 16 (3 - 2 k) (-2 + k - m) (-1 + k - m)  \text{iterm}(m, k - 2,i) 
 \end{align*} 
 lies in $3m(m-1)\mathbb{Z}[1/2]$.

That will prove that the $ (m-1 ) m ( 2 m+1) d(m, k-1 )$ are  integer multiples of  $3m(m-1)$.

Put 
$$\text{frac1}(m,k,i)=\frac{3 (m-1) m \binom{2 (k-1)}{k-1} (-2 k+2
   m+1) \binom{k-1}{i} \binom{m}{i} \binom{i}{-k+m+1}}{(2
   i-1) (2 m-2 i-1)}$$
   and 
   $$\text{frac2}(m,k,i)=6  (k-m-1)\binom{2 (k-1)}{k-1}  \binom{k-1}{i} \binom{m}{i} \binom{i}{-k+m+1}.$$

Then $\text{frac1}(m,k,i)+\text{frac2}(m,k,i)$ equals 
   \begin{align*}&(2 - 2 k + m) (3 - 2 k + m) (1 - 2 k + 2 m)  \text{iterm}(m, k - 1,i)\\&+ 
 16 (3 - 2 k) (-2 + k - m) (-1 + k - m)  \text{iterm}(m, k - 2,i) ,
 \end{align*}

so it suffices to show that $\text{frac1}(m,k,i)/(6m(m-1))$ and $\text{frac2}(m,k,i)/(6m(m-1))$, which make sense for $m\geq2$,
  lie in $\mathbb{Z}[1/2]$ for $m\geq 2$.
 Recall that the Catalan numbers
 $$C(i)=\frac{\binom{2 i}{i}}{i+1}$$ are integers. See

[A000108](https://oeis.org/A000108)

We now look at $\text{frac1}(m,k,i)/(6m(m-1))$.

If $\text{frac1}(m,k,i)$ is nonzero then $ m\geq k-1\geq i\geq m+1-k\geq 0$. 
We distinguish two cases: $ m=k-1\geq i\geq 0$ and $ m> k-1\geq i\geq m+1-k\geq 0$.

First let $ m=k-1\geq i\geq 0$. If $i=k-1$, then 
$$\text{frac1}(m,k,i)/(6m(m-1))=\text{frac1}(k-1,k,k-1)/(6(k-1)(k-2))=C(k-2).$$

Similarly $\text{frac1}(k-1,k,0)/(6(k-1)(k-2))=C(k-2).$

So we may assume $0<i<m=k-1$.
Then

$\text{frac1}(m,k,i)/(6m(m-1))=\text{frac1}(m,m+1,i)/(6m(m-1))$ equals

$$\small
\frac{-(2 i-2)! (2 m)! (-2 i+2 m-2)!}{2 (i!)^2 (2 i-1)!
   ((m-i)!)^2 (-2 i+2 m-1)!}$$ and we must show it takes values in $\mathbb{Z}[1/2]$.

This is the kind of expression to which one may apply the method of Floors explained in

[question 26336](https://mathoverflow.net/q/26336).

According to the method it suffices to check that $\text{test}(m,i,2n+1)\geq0$ for $n\geq1$, where
\begin{align*}
\text{test}(m,i,q)=&\\-2& \left\lfloor \frac{m-i}{q}\right\rfloor +\left\lfloor
   \frac{-2 i+2 m-2}{q}\right\rfloor -\left\lfloor \frac{-2
   i+2 m-1}{q}\right\rfloor\\ -2& \left\lfloor
   \frac{i}{q}\right\rfloor +\left\lfloor \frac{2
   i-2}{q}\right\rfloor -\left\lfloor \frac{2
   i-1}{q}\right\rfloor +\left\lfloor \frac{2
   m}{q}\right\rfloor
.\end{align*}

This is a tedious puzzle. For fixed $q$ the function $\text{test}(m,i,q)$ is periodic of period $q$ in both variables $i$ and $m$.
So for fixed $q$ one may simply compute all values. We do it for $3\leq q=2n+1<17$. The results are nonnegative.
But if $q$ is large we need to be more efficient. If both $q=2n+1$ and $m$ are
fixed, then $\text{test}(m,i,q)$ can only change value where at least one of the Floors jumps as a function of $i$. So it suffices to sample around the jumping
points (modulo $q$). We know where they are. More specifically, we only need to consider the 15 cases where one of $i-1$, $i$, $i+1$ lies in 
$\{0, 1, -1 + m, m,  -2 + m - n, -1 + m - n, 1 + n\}$.
So we can eliminate $i$ at the expense of having 15 cases. Similarly we can eliminate $m$ for each of those cases, ending up with
153 test functions that depend on $n$ only. Each test function is a linear combination of seven Floors.
Each of the Floors stabilises after $n$ has reached an easily computable bound.
For instance $\left\lfloor -\frac{8}{2 n+1}\right\rfloor$ is constant for $n\geq4$.
In fact the bound 5 suffices for all $7\times 153$ Floors. Compute the 153 stable values. They are nonnegative. 
 This solves the puzzle; the check for $3\leq q=2n+1<17$ was overkill.

So we now turn to the case $ m> k-1\geq i\geq m+1-k\geq 0$.
 Then 
 $$\text{frac1}(m,k,i)/(6m(m-1)C(i-1))$$ equals $$\small\frac{i! (2 k-2)! m! (-2 i+2 m-2)! (-2 k+2 m+1)!}{(2 i)! (k-1)! (-i+k-1)! (m-i)! (-2 i+2 m-1)!
   (-k+m+1)! (2 m-2 k)! (i+k-m-1)!}
 $$

We use  the method of Floors again to show that  $\text{frac1}(m,k,i)/(6m(m-1)C(i-1))\in \mathbb{Z}[1/2]$.
This time we eliminate $k$, $m$, $i$ in that order and take $n\geq6$ as bound where all  $13\times 3508$ Floors are stable.

**So we have shown that**  $\text{frac1}(m,k,i)/(6m(m-1))$ 
  lies in $\mathbb{Z}[1/2]$ for $m\geq 2$.
Remains showing that $\text{frac2}(m,k,i)/(6m(m-1))$ 
  lies in $\mathbb{Z}[1/2]$ for $m\geq 2$.

If $\text{frac2}(m,k,i)$ is nonzero then $m> k-1\geq i\geq m+1-k>0$ and
$\text{frac2}(m,k,i)/(6m(m-1))$ 
equals

$$\frac{-(2 k-2)! (m-2)!}{i! (k-1)! (-i+k-1)! (m-i)! (m-k)!
   (i+k-m-1)!}$$

This can be treated like the previous case. We eliminate $k$, $m$, $i$ in that order and take $n\geq6$ as bound where all  $8\times 1278$ Floors are stable.

**Done**

Comment: So, this problem is probably not suitable on a midterm :)

Comment: It was take home.